# Image mapping with different screen sizes.

Tags: html, css

So guys If u want code I can provide it! I made a website for planets which had a big photo of planets and I used image mapping on it (from W3Schools). Problem is that when I open the same website on a bigger laptop image gets bigger since I am using bootstrap and Image mapping gets messed up. Is there any solution to this ? Can I use image mapping for all screens ?

Comment: Check out the media queries and grid options. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

You need to set max-width for your image tag so it doesn't get as big as it gets. You also need to set the @media query for the screen size you are on. But you can also set your image on a percentage of how big it's container is. (e.g) width: 50%;

For example:

```
//Desktop or Landscape Tablet Screen Size
@media all and (min-width: 981px) {
img {
max-width: 400px;
}
}
```